# I can't to enforce video of iframe to mute ( https://bunny.net)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, next.js13

The problem is when I go to another page unmute the video (also iframe from bunny.net) and return to this page, the player is unmuted.

The iframe saves the state of the player in localStorage. I try to change it but

> The error you're encountering is due to a security restriction known as the Same-Origin Policy. Browsers enforce this policy to prevent scripts on one domain from accessing properties and methods of documents or iframes on a different domain.

[image]

[excursion page](https://www.pinktravel.md/excursions)

this is the code:

```
'use client'
  
  import { useParams } from 'next/navigation'
  import styles from './ExcursionCard.module.scss'
  import Image from 'next/image'
  
  import { useClientTranslation } from '@/hooks'
  import { LocationIcon } from '@/icons'
  import { IExcursion } from '@/types'
  import { capitalize } from '@/utils'
  import { Button } from '..'
  
  const formatUrlForBunnyVideo = (
    video?: string,
    autoplay = false,
    loop = false,
    muted = false,
    preload = true,
    responsive = true,
  ) => {
    if (!video) return null
  
    return `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BUNNYCDN_DIRECTPLAY}/${video}?autoplay=${autoplay}&loop=${loop}&muted=${muted}&preload=${preload}&responsive=${responsive}`
  }
  
  export const ExcursionCard = ({
    slug,
    cities,
    price,
    videos,
    destination,
    images,
    type = videos?.length ? 'video' : 'image',
  }: IExcursion) => {
    const { locale } = useParams()
    const { common: t } = useClientTranslation()
    const { menu: menuTranslations } = useClientTranslation()
  
    const videoUrl = formatUrlForBunnyVideo(videos?.[0], true, true, true, true, true)
  
    return (
      <div className={styles['excursion-card']}>
        {type === 'image' && images?.[0] && (
          <Image
            src={images?.[0]}
            alt={destination.country}
            className={styles['excursion-card__image']}
            width={400}
            height={300}
          />
        )}
  
        {type === 'video' && videoUrl && (
          <div className={styles['excursion-card__video']}>
            <iframe
              src={videoUrl}
              loading="lazy"
              allow="accelerometer;gyroscope;autoplay;encrypted-media;picture-in-picture;"
              allowFullScreen
              style={{
                border: 0,
                position: 'absolute',
                top: 0,
                height: '100%',
                width: '100%',
                userSelect: 'none',
              }}
            ></iframe>
          </div>
        )}
        <div className={styles.overlay}></div>
            
        <div className={styles['excursion-card__content']}>
          <div className={styles['excursion-card__info']}>
            <h3 className={styles['excursion-card__name']}>
              {menuTranslations[destination.country as keyof typeof menuTranslations]}
            </h3>
            <div className={styles['excursion-card__location']}>
              <ul>
                {[t.chisinau, ...cities]?.map((city, idx) => (
                  <li key={city}>
                    {idx === 0 && <LocationIcon />}
                    <span>
                      {capitalize(city)}
                      {idx !== cities.length && ' - '}
                    </span>
                  </li>
                ))}
              </ul>
                
              <div className={styles['excursion-card__price']}>
                <span>{t.from}</span>
                <span className={styles['excursion-card__price-value']}>€{price}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <Button
            className={styles['excursion-card__button']}
            fullWidth
            variant="pink"
            href={`/${locale}/excursions/${slug}`}
          >
            {t.see_details}
          </Button>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
```